# Admob banners hurting iOS framerate

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, admob

I am creating a iOS game using swift and spritekit and have run into a problem displaying ads from admob. The test ads work fine and I don't have any problems, but as soon as I start calling live ads, my frame drops significantly and really hurts gameplay. I'm not quite sure what the problem is and have tried to follow the documentation and can't figure out what the problem is. Here is my code that handles the calling and displaying of ads. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

```
func createIntAd() {

    interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-8872492368219215/3269040884")
    self.interstitial.load(GADRequest())
}

func showAd()
{
    if (self.interstitial.isReady)
    {
        self.interstitial.present(fromRootViewController: self)//Whatever  shows the ad
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5.0, target: self, selector: #selector(createIntAd), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    print("Google Mobile Ads SDK version: " + GADRequest.sdkVersion())
    bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-8872492368219215/1792307689"
    bannerView.rootViewController = self
    bannerView.load(GADRequest())

    if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
        // Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'
        if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
            // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
            scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
            scene.adDelegate = self
            // Present the scene
            view.presentScene(scene)
        }

        view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        view.showsFPS = false
        view.showsNodeCount = false
        createIntAd()
    }
    FIRMessaging.messaging().subscribe(toTopic: "/topics/news")
}
```

Comment: I find that it's better to not show ads during gameplay anyway, as they do this, but it also bothers the user. Personally, I would just not show the ad during gameplay if you can. You could always show it before and after the game too

Comment: Why are you creating a new ad every 5 seconds?  You should only be creating a new ad once the old ad is removed